# Model & History Model (Same fields), Copy data from one to another

Tags: django, django-models

I have a two models, `A` and `HistoryA`

```
class A(models.Model):
    title = ....
    slug = ....
    done = ....
    date_done = ....

class HistoryA(models.Model):
    parent = ForeignKey(A)
    title = ....
    slug = ....
    done = ....
    date_done = ....
```

When a user after creating a `A` instance, try to edit it; a new instance of `HistoryA` is created saving all the old data. But if that user decides to discard the changes, the old data that were in `HistoryA` must move back to `A`

How I can copy all the value from `HistoryA` to `A`, without typing all the fields one by one, like:

```
# Just an example
A_instance.attributes = HistotyA_instance.attributes
A_instance.save()
```

> Basically it's just a way to create History for a model.

Answer (score 2):

You can access a model's data(or any object data), using `__dict__` method. For storing history of a model, rather than doing it the way you have mentioned, its better to use a third party libray like [django-simple-history](https://django-simple-history.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#install). For example you can use it like this:

```
from simple_history.models import HistoricalRecords


class A(models.Model):
    title = ....
    slug = ....
    done = ....
    date_done = ....
    history = HistoricalRecords()
```

There are [many other libraries](https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/model-audit/) as well which you can look into.

Comment: I don't want to use third party app since I just want to use History for only one model, no need to add a whole third package for that.